# network activity indicator is not shown on iPhone (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, ios, android-activity, statusbar, indicator

just to test it I enabled the activity indicator of the status bar as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible: TRUE]; 

    //...
}
```

I never disable the indicator so it should always be visible, but it isn't. It is visible in the iPhone Simulator but not on the device. Why?

Comment: Do you disable the indicator anywhere else in your code at all (not necessarily in the app delegate) ?

Comment: And does it happen on iOS 5 device only ? Can you reproduce this on 4.3 device ?

Comment: Currently I cannot check other iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

Please not that the application is not active when a call is made to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You should move this to the `viewDidLoad` method instead. Thus the code should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    // Some other code goes here...
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Or you could put this code anywhere else where the view has been loaded. Do not forget to stop it once the data has been loaded.

Comment: That's really strange. I switched off my test phone for a day because I had to work on another project. Today I tried your proposal and it works. But it also works if I make this call in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I also noticed that the WLAN icon is now present which I also missed before. So the whole problem disappeared, but I don't know why. I already tried to solve it earlier by switching the phone off and on again. But this didn't matter. The only difference is that the phone now has been off a longer time ...?!

Comment: The _viewDidLoad_ is only called when the application is terminated. So you must terminate the application before you test this. You should really take a look at your application and call this before you make any network call. When you get an answer from the server, you should disable the network indicator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The application is terminated every time before a new build is loaded. And a new build is required to test changes. Do you mean something else?